# How to disable HTTP Basic Auth for specific API endpoints on Twisted-Klein server

Tags: python, twisted, twistd

I have simple `Twisted-Klein` server, with HTTP Basic Auth enabled globally:

```
from klein import Klein
import attr
from zope.interface import implementer
from twisted.cred.portal import IRealm
from twisted.internet.defer import succeed
from twisted.cred.portal import Portal
from twisted.cred.checkers import FilePasswordDB
from twisted.web.resource import IResource
from twisted.web.guard import HTTPAuthSessionWrapper, BasicCredentialFactory
from werkzeug.datastructures import MultiDict
from bson import json_util
import json


app = Klein()


# health check
@app.route('/health', methods=['GET'])
def health_check(request):
    return ''


# dataset query API
@app.route('/query/<path:expression>', methods=['GET'])
def query(request, expression):
    response = evaluate_expression(expression)
    return response


@implementer(IRealm)
@attr.s
class HTTPAuthRealm(object):
    resource = attr.ib()

    def requestAvatar(self, avatarId, mind, *interfaces):
        return succeed((IResource, self.resource, lambda: None))


def resource():
    realm = HTTPAuthRealm(resource=app.resource())
    portal = Portal(realm, [FilePasswordDB('./configs/server-auth.db')])
    credential_factory = BasicCredentialFactory('Authentication required')
    return HTTPAuthSessionWrapper(portal, [credential_factory])
```

I want to disable auth for only specific API endpoints, for example, in this case for `/health` API endpoint. I've read the docs, but just cant wrap my mind around it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to only wrap the part of the hierarchy that you want authentication for:

```
from twisted.web.resource import Resource

class Health(Resource):
    # ...

def resource():
    realm = HTTPAuthRealm(resource=app.resource())
    portal = Portal(realm, [FilePasswordDB('./configs/server-auth.db')])
    credential_factory = BasicCredentialFactory('Authentication required')
    guarded = HTTPAuthSessionWrapper(portal, [credential_factory])

    root = Resource()
    root.putChild(b"health", Health())
    root.putChild(b"this-stuff-requires-auth", guarded)

    return root
```

The normal resource traversal logic used for dispatching requests will start at `root`.  If the request is for `/health` (or any child) then it goes to `root`'s `health` child - which is the `Health` instance created in this example.  Note how the `HTTPAuthSessionWrapper` doesn't get involved there.  If the request is for `/this-stuff-requires-auth` (or any child) then traversal *does* go through the auth wrapper and so authentication is required.

Another approach is to vary your avatar based on the credentials.  In this scheme, you actually still authenticate everyone but you authorize anonymous users to access some of the hierarchy.

```
from twisted.cred.checkers import ANONYMOUS

@implementer(IRealm)
@attr.s
class HTTPAuthRealm(object):
    def requestAvatar(self, avatarId, mind, *interfaces):
        avatar = Resource()
        avatar.putChild(b"health", Health())
        if avatarId is not ANONYMOUS:
            avatar.putChild(b"this-stuff-requires-auth", SecretResource())
        return succeed((IResource, avatar, lambda: None))
```

You'll also need to configure your portal with a credentials checker for anonymous credentials:

```
from twisted.cred.checkers import AllowAnonymousAccess

portal = Portal(
    realm, [
        FilePasswordDB('./configs/server-auth.db'),
        AllowAnonymousAccess(),
    ],
)
```

In this approach, `HTTPAuthSessionWrapper` is again your root resource.

Anonymous requests are associated with the `ANONYMOUS` avatar identifier and `HTTPAuthRealm` gives back an `IResource` which only knows about the resources that should be available to anonymous users.

Requests with valid user credentials are associated with a different avatar identifier (usually their username) and `HTTPAuthRealm` gives back an `IResource` with more children attached to it, granting more access.

Comment: Thanks! This works! If I dont want to have pre-path for my auth APIs, how would I do this? I've tried something like: `root.putChild(b'', guarded)`, but I get `404 No Such Resource` error when I try to query the APIs.

Comment: There's a way to do what you want.  It involves customizing the result of `requestAvatar` instead of fiddling with the resource hierarchy that includes HTTPAuthSessionWrapper.  Not feeling up to writing up a full example right now, possibly later though.

Comment: Ok thanks. I'd appreciate if you can show me an example of it.

Comment: Added some stuff, maybe that helps.